Заставить postfix отправлять письма через порт 465 или 578
Когда я пытаюсь отправить email командой echo "test" | mail test@srv1.mail-tester.com, через некоторое время в mailq я вижу следующее:
C979322CB3      322 Mon Aug 12 12:28:20  <мой_пользователь>@<мой_домен>
 (connect to reception.mail-tester.com[94.23.206.89]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         test@srv1.mail-tester.com

На сколько я понимаю, это значит, что подключиться к серверу mail-tester.com на порту 25 не получилось. Видимо, потому что порт 25 заблокирован хостингом. Чтобы обойти это, я хочу отправлять письма через порты 465 или 578, по SMTPS. После гугления, я добавил следующее в /etc/postfix/master.cf:
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

но ничего вообще не поменялось. Помогите, пожалуйста, настроить шифрование и отправку через порты 465 или 578.

А почему вы решили, что провайдер настолько глупый, что по-вашему не додумался блокировать порты 465 и 578?)

@andreymal я в этом не разбираюсь, можете прогуглить. 25 порт всегда блокируют, 465 и 578 - нет.

Ну вот например на хостинге TimeWeb заблокировано всё перечисленное

@andreymal хорошо, возможно. Но это не суть вопроса. Даже если так, мне интересно узнать, как перенастроить postfix на другой порт.

Сверьте main.cf с этими настройками:
# Включить использование TLS
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert 
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key

# Включить SASL
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

# Параметры для сервиса submission
submission_service_type = master
submission_service_name = submission
submission_service_port = 587  # или 465, в зависимости от выбранного порта
submission_service_protocol = smtp
submission_service_tls_security_level = encrypt

# Определить домен для отправки почты
myorigin = example.com # Замените на ваш домен


При sudo postfix reload выдаёт /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: submission_... (такие строки для всех параметров, начинающихся с submission_). Похоже, таких параметров он не знает. smtpd_tls_cert_file и smtpd_tls_key_file уже были указаны на /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem и /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key соответственно.
